# Why is my background service or my broadcast receiver being killed with main activity?

Tags: java, android, cordova, service

I want independent always running service like Pushbullet, SmartLockScreen or WhatsApp has, that is waiting for some event to happen. I have already tried foreground service, returning START_STICKY in onStartCommand, restarting the service in onTaskRemoved and running service in separate process using android:process.

My service class:

```
public class CallService  extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true);
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, startIntent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    this.startForeground(1, builder.build());
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".CallService" android:persistent="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="cz.volamakler.CallService" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tried using broadcast receiver and it gets killed with main activity too.

```
    public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}

public class CallReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }
}
```

Comment: when i close the application(ui)

Comment: means when you press "back" on your main activity? (when `finish()` method is called)

Comment: Yes, i think so. When the main activity is stopped, the service is stopped too.

Comment: it is not possible, if you call `startService()` from your activity and then call `finiish()` (back pressed) the service is still in started state (morover you called `startForeground` so it will survive removing from `Recent Apps` view)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are running your service in same ui thread. Looper used is same as that of application's ui thread from which you are starting the service. You need to do the following:

Create a seperate Handler Thread. Then do your tasks inside handlemessage.

```
  public class CallService  extends Service {
            private Looper mServiceLooper;
          private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

          // Handler that receives messages from the thread
          private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
              public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
                  super(looper);
              }
              @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
                  // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
                  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
                  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                      synchronized (this) {
                          try {
                              wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
                  // the service in the middle of handling another job
                  stopSelf(msg.arg1);
              }
          }
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
// For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
      // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
      Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
      msg.arg1 = startId;
      mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                return START_STICKY;
            }
           @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
      }
            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

            }
            @Override
            public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
                Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
                restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

                PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmService.set(
                        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                        restartServicePendingIntent);

                super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
            }
            }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not doing what i want. I want independent always running service like Pushbullet, SmartLockScreen or WhatsApp has, that is waiting for some event to happen.

Comment: which event you want to listen to ? You can use broadcast receivers in that case.

Comment: I could use broadcast receiver, but i would run into the same problem - the broadcast receiver would be killed with my main activity.

Comment: register it in manifest it will not be killed when your application is killed.If you register it in your activity then it will be unregistered in ondestroy, This is basic difference between registering in manifest and registering in activity

Comment: I already tried:<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: hen you should get call in onReceive of CallReceiver.

Comment: I do, but it always did. The Receiver gets killed with the main activity, that's the problem.